# Quoted code changes color when imported from source

Tags: listings, quoting

I wrote a simple code to highlight syntax when I quote some C++ in latex. However, when the code is directly imported from a source file, the headers are in blue instead of green, this being the only difference between codes.

1) Output from a C++ code directly hardcoded

[image: Hardcoded C++]

2) Output from a C++ code in a file, imported with:

```
\lstinputlisting[language=C++, firstline=1, lastline=10]{Hello.cpp}
```

[image: Imported code]

As you can see, the headers are now blue!

Here is the latex code I used to do this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{fullpage}

\newcommand{\grayScale}{0.95} % Can change the gray level here
\definecolor{codeBackground}{rgb}{\grayScale ,\grayScale ,\grayScale}
\definecolor{forestGreen}{rgb}{0.13,0.55,0.13}

\begin{document}

% Using typewriter font: \ttfamily inside \lstset
\lstset{
    language=C++,
    backgroundcolor=\color{codeBackground},
    tabsize=4,
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    showspaces=false,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    identifierstyle=\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    stringstyle=\color{red},
    commentstyle=\color{gray},
    numberstyle=\color{magenta},
    morecomment=[l][\color{forestGreen}]{\#}                
}
\lstset{literate=% Colors the digits
   *{0}{{{\color{red!20!violet}0}}}1
    {1}{{{\color{red!20!violet}1}}}1
    {2}{{{\color{red!20!violet}2}}}1
    {3}{{{\color{red!20!violet}3}}}1
    {4}{{{\color{red!20!violet}4}}}1
    {5}{{{\color{red!20!violet}5}}}1
    {6}{{{\color{red!20!violet}6}}}1
    {7}{{{\color{red!20!violet}7}}}1
    {8}{{{\color{red!20!violet}8}}}1
    {9}{{{\color{red!20!violet}9}}}1
}
\begin{lstlisting}
% HERE IS MY HARDCODED C++
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
// Template for C++ quoting
/*
    Warning: If line too long, will go outside the color box
*/
int main(void)
{
    cout << "Hello World" << endl;
    return 0; // Numbers are colored when not in comment nor strings
}
\end{lstlisting}

% FROM A SOURCE FILE
\lstinputlisting[language=C++, firstline=1, lastline=10]{Hello.cpp}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! I can't reproduce the output you show from the sourced file. Maybe this is because I have the contents wrong. I copied the contents of the `lstlisting` environment into a file named `Hello.cpp`. But the last 2 lines do not show in the output.

Comment: I guess last line needs to be 12 rather than 10...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works if you specify exactly the same settings i.e. none:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{fullpage}

\newcommand{\grayScale}{0.95} % Can change the gray level here
\definecolor{codeBackground}{rgb}{\grayScale ,\grayScale ,\grayScale}
\definecolor{forestGreen}{rgb}{0.13,0.55,0.13}

\begin{document}

% Using typewriter font: \ttfamily inside \lstset
\lstset{
    language=C++,
    backgroundcolor=\color{codeBackground},
    tabsize=4,
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    showspaces=false,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    identifierstyle=\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    stringstyle=\color{red},
    commentstyle=\color{gray},
    numberstyle=\color{magenta},
    morecomment=[l][\color{forestGreen}]{\#}
}
\lstset{literate=% Colors the digits
   *{0}{{{\color{red!20!violet}0}}}1
    {1}{{{\color{red!20!violet}1}}}1
    {2}{{{\color{red!20!violet}2}}}1
    {3}{{{\color{red!20!violet}3}}}1
    {4}{{{\color{red!20!violet}4}}}1
    {5}{{{\color{red!20!violet}5}}}1
    {6}{{{\color{red!20!violet}6}}}1
    {7}{{{\color{red!20!violet}7}}}1
    {8}{{{\color{red!20!violet}8}}}1
    {9}{{{\color{red!20!violet}9}}}1
}
\begin{lstlisting}
% HERE IS MY HARDCODED C++
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
// Template for C++ quoting
/*
    Warning: If line too long, will go outside the color box
*/
int main(void)
{
    cout << "Hello World" << endl;
    return 0; // Numbers are colored when not in comment nor strings
}
\end{lstlisting}

% FROM A SOURCE FILE
\lstinputlisting[firstline=1, lastline=12]{Hello.cpp}

\end{document}
```

[image: syntax in green]

Comment: You're right. If I want to redefine some parameters for let's say Python, I have to re-write all the `\lstset` and then call `\begin{lstlisting}` again or there is a way to refer to a specific definition of `\lstset`?

Comment: @Shinagan Sorry. I don't know. I never use it. I just fiddled. Could be a new question?

Comment: Alright, I'll have a look at the doc and if I can't find out I'll ask a new question!